# Why is $\cos(x)^2$ written as $\cos^2(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, notation

I'm just wondering why the square of $\cos(x)$ (i.e.: $(\cos(x))*(\cos(x))$) is almost universally written in the form $\cos^2(x)$ rather than $\cos(x)^2$.  This seems particularly bizarre when one considers that $\cos^{-1}(x) \ne \cos(x)^{-1}$.

Comment: $\cos : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a function. Whenever one has a function $g: X\to \mathbb R$, $g^2 : X\to\mathbb R$ is the function given by 

$$g^2(x) := (g(x))^2.$$

So the notation $\cos^2$ seems natural.

Comment: For me, the notation $g^2(x)$ is either read as $g(g(x))$ or $g(x)^2$, depending on the context. It seems that one of the recent trends is to write $g(g(x)) = g^{\circ2}(x)$, though.

Comment: $\cos^2(x)$ may be misinterpreted as $\cos(\cos x)$, which is how you're supposed to interpret the exponent in $\cos^{-1}(x)$. It's confusing, but somehow the two meanings don't conflict that often, so it's a convension that is kept.

Comment: Blame John Hershel, who wrote an article in the "Philosophical Transactions of London" in 1813, where he introduced the notations $\sin^{-1}$ and $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: @Arthur really?  I've never seen $\cos^2(x)$ and thought $\cos(\cos^2(x))$.  Is there any common analogue elsewhere?  Also, I'm having a lot of trouble seeing what you mean when you say, "which is how you're supposed to interpret the exponent in $\cos^{−1}(x)$".  Could you please clarify in some way or another?  Thanks!

Comment: @BenSandeen What I mean is that $\cos^{-1}x$ is _not_ $\frac1{\cos x}$. It is the function defined by $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)=\cos(\cos^{-1}x)=x$. That is the interpretation of exponents that would make $\cos^2 x$ into $\cos(\cos x)$.

Comment: @Arthur That makes perfect sense now, thank you

Comment: See also: [What is cos²(x)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108131)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we can safely drop the brackets without losing ambiguity, which means less effort when writing it out by hand.
$$
\cos^2x = \cos^2(x) = \cos(x)^2 \neq \cos x^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are several competing notations. These seem to be the standard interpretations. The goal seems to be to use the least number of parenthesis and still be understandable.

$\left .
\begin{matrix}
    \cos(\cos(x)) \\
    (\cos(x))^2 \\
\end{matrix}
\right\} = \cos^2(x) = \cos(x)^2$

$\left .
\begin{matrix}
    \dfrac{1}{cos(x)} \\
    \arccos(x)
\end{matrix}
\right\} = \cos^{-1}(x)$

$\cos(x^2) = \cos(x)^2 = \cos x^2$

Please note that $\cos(x)^2$ is the most ambiguous of the group and I personally feel that it should be avoided as much as possible.

Generally, the context **should** make it clear which meaning is being used.

Answer (score 2):

This is because composition of functions are very rare when you are talking about trigonometric functions.

For any other $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{R}$, it may make sense to calculate $f(f(x))$, however for $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$, composition like $\cos(\cos(x))$ is not a frequent use. That's why a misunderstanding in $\cos^2(x)$ is not so much in concern.

On the other hand, when it is about $\arcsin(x)$ and $\csc(x)$, there are conflicts about the use of $\sin^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Imo $\mathrm{sin}^{-1}$ ought to mean the reciprocal of $\sin$. After all, $\sin$ neither injective nor surjective, so it certainly doesn't have a two-sided inverse with respect to composition.

Answer (score 1):

Well because when you write 
$$
\cos(x)^2 
$$
it can be misunderstood as cosine of (square of x) not the square of the whole value so to avoid confusion its written as
$$\cos^2(x)=(\cos(x))^2$$

Comment: No, cosine of (square of x) would be written $\cos(x^2)$, never $\cos(x)^2$. Some ambiguity is possible though when leaving out the parentheses entirely (as sometimes done with trigonometric functions) as in $\cos x^2$, but that case is not the subject of the current question.